# how to add new entries in struct which is member of class using inheritance

Tags: c++, class, struct

```
class A
{
    public:
        typedef struct st
        {
            int x;
            int y;
        }st;
};
```

I have class A which has a structure as public member variable. I want to add some new entries in above struct st. I used inheritance. is it possible to add new entries in that structure without changing it's name (st).

```
class B:public A
{
};
```

Please help me out.

Comment: continue to above question, i have one more doubt. why B::st* obj = NULL; obj = new A::st [10]; this is not possible. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A type always remains the same throughout the entire program. `A::st` has members `x` and `y`. No more, no less - regardless of any subclasses that `A` might have. And no type can have the same name as another type (within the same namespace).

However, just as you can extend the class `A` by creating a subclass `B`, you can also extend the class `A::st` by creating a subclass. If you wish, you can declare the subclass of `A::st` as a member class of `B` like so:

```
class B:public A
{
    struct st : A::st
    {
        int z;
    };
};
```

Now, `B::st` is a subclass of `A::st`, and hides `B::A::st` within the namespace of `B`.

Comment: continue to above question, i have one more doubt. why B::st* obj = NULL;
obj = new A::st [10]; this is not possible. ?

Comment: @Spartacus Correct. A pointer to parent is not implicitly convertible into pointer to derived.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add additional members to the original struct within A (btw: why that C-style typedef? You simply don't need it in C++...).

The only thing you can do is extending your struct within B by creating a new data type:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    struct st
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    };
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    struct st : A::st
    {
        int z;
    };
};
```

Be aware, however, that that these are different data types and you risk type erasure under certain circumstances:

```cpp
B::st instance;
A::st& reference      = instance;  // OK
A::st* pointer        = &instance; // OK
A::st anotherInstance = instance;  // works, but z gets erased!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, yes, you can extend `st` inside `B`.  Add an inner struct in `B` that inherits from `A::st`.

https://godbolt.org/g/sWfYWY

```
class A
{
public:
    struct St
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    };
    St st;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    struct St : public A::St
    {
        int z;
    };
    St st;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.st.x = 1;
    a.st.y = 2;

    B b;
    b.st.x = 3;
    b.st.y = 4;
    b.st.z = 5;

    return 0;
}
```